# And/or multiple optional arguments in function - R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, optional-arguments

I'm trying to create a function with two arguments, where it needs the input of at least one of them. Specifically, the function has as arguments month and/or day of the week.

```
function.month_weekday <- function(month, weekday){
  ifelse (month %in% 1:4 & weekday %in% 1:5, "ANSWER A", 
          ifelse (month %in% 1:4 & is.null(weekday), "ANSWER B",
              ifelse (is.null(month) & weekday %in% 1:5, "ANSWER C",
                      "Error")))
}
```

The problem I'm having is how can I put both arguments as optional with the mandatory of at least one? `is.null()` doesn't seem to works, as also `== NULL` or `== var(0)`.

Comment: To avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask for help with your proposed Y solution and not actual X problem, try fleshing out with broad picture of: *I'm trying to filter a df by month and/or day*. Chances are your process can be different.

Comment: @Parfait problem XY fixed!. I didn't know there was a problem like that one. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted you to extend the broader dataframe picture even illustrate with some data, NOT remove it. Now it is more an XY Problem! Simply explain the overall picture of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Parfait got it. Thanks !

Comment: Do we have to ask you [why five times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#comment436926_66378) as you are *still* not answering the full picture? What is your initial data and what is the problem (i.e., filtering rows, calculating columns)? Forget this function need for a second and step back and give us the bigger picture. You are too much into the weeds.